# ASP.NET MVC Register custom Model Binder for all ViewModels

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have created a Custom Model Binder that works perfectly.

All my ViewModels extend the BaseViewModel however when I register the Model Binder for BaseViewModel it just doesn't run.

If I register every ViewModel "by hand" like the following line it works perfectly

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(ArticlesViewModel)] =  new ContextDataBinder();
```

What I need to know if there is a way to do that kind of registration for **all my viewModels without register all viewModels one by one**.

Comment: `ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new ContextDataBinder();`

Comment: DefaultBinder works but just ruins all my searches , every time I do a search it just devolves the viewModel if all the data not filtering it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was commented in my original post you can register all the model blinders by replacing the default binder

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new ContextDataBinder();
```

However that **didn't worked for my specific case** because the ViewModels that the framework creates automatically always return  the previous ViewModel (in searches for example it doesn't return me filtered results but all the results).

I ended up creating a List of types containing the type of only the ViewModels that actually need to pass trough the ModelBinder and with a foreach e register them all one by one.